# Cannot change text box value in IE 11 in a ModalWindow

Tags: internet-explorer, wicket, internet-explorer-11

I am able to click the text in a text box in my `ModalWindow` and edit. When I save and then repeat the process, I cannot click the text in the text box and make changes.

This is only happening in IE 11. I can click the X to clear the text box and then set a value, but I should not have to do that. I am not sure if there is a problem in my code, with IE 11, or with Wicket. My Quickstart is using Wicket 7.0.0, but I have similar behavior in Wicket 6.18.0.

Here is the version of IE 11 I am running:

- Version: 11.0.9600.17501
- Update Versions: 11.0.15 (KB3008923)
- Product ID: 00150-20000-00002-AA803

Below are are steps that I used with my Wicket Quickstart:

1. In HomePage, click "openWindowLink"
2. The ModalWindow opens. Click on the text in the text box and make an edit. Click Save.
3. the ModalWindow closes. Click "openWindowLink" again.
4. The ModalWindow opens. Click on the text in the text box and try to make an edit.
5. Observe that you cannot click the text and get a cursor to edit.

Here are parts of the Quickstart that I think are relevant:

HomePage.java

```
    @Override
    public void onInitialize()
    {
        super.onInitialize();

        final ModalWindow modal = new ModalWindow("modal");
        modal.setPageCreator(new ModalWindow.PageCreator()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public Page createPage()
            {
                return new IEModalPage();
            }
        });
        add(modal);

        add(new AjaxLink<Void>("openWindowLink")
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target)
            {
                modal.show(target);
            }
        });
    }
```

HomePage.html

```
    <body>
        <a wicket:id="openWindowLink">Click to open the modal window</a>
        <div wicket:id="modal"></div>
    </body>
```

IEModalPage.java

```
public class IEModalPage extends WebPage
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String value = "clickme";

    @Override
    public void onInitialize()
    {
        super.onInitialize();

        Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("pageForm");
        add(form);

        form.add(new TextField<String>("captureValue", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "value")));

        form.add(new AjaxSubmitLink("saveButton")
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form)
            {
                System.out.println(value);
                ModalWindow.closeCurrent(target);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

IEModalPage.html

```
<body>
    <form wicket:id="pageForm">
        Click in the text box and make sure you see a cursor: <input type="text" wicket:id="captureValue" />
        <br />
        <input type ="submit" value="Save" wicket:id="saveButton" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you reproduce the issue at http://examples7-apachewicket.rhcloud.com/ajax/modal-window ? I have no IE11 around to test myself, sorry!

Comment: Yes, it reproduces when I click in the date text field. The first time it works and the second time it doesn't. I can refresh the page with F5 and it will work again the first time.

Comment: @martin-g, the problem only replicates using the "Show modal dialog with a page", so I am suspicious the problem is iframe related. I also noticed that if I "break" the window on attempt 2 with the page modal then the "Show modal dialog with panel" link also results in a broken state.

Also, I am able to tab into the text box. It seems that only the click has a problem.

Comment: This is reported as a bug in the Wicket JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-6082

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this case is to use a work around to focus on the first available text box. In this example, I am only adding this focus feature when the user is using IE 11. In my base modal page:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response)
{
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forScript(
        "if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(window, 'ActiveXObject') && !window.ActiveXObject) {" +
        "   $(document).ready(function(){$('input[type=text]').first().focus();});" +
        "}",
        "IE11Focus"));
}
```